# Minecraft Version not showing in Launcher (even though i've renamed everything)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I'm probably just an idiot, but I'm trying to create a new profile for 1.6.2 to use with single player commmands/worldedit, and I can't get the new modded version to show up in the launcher.

What the other threads about this similar issue all said was to make sure everything (the folder, the .jar, the .json, and the id in the .json) had the same name, but mine all do, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: have you tried making a new profile that uses 1.6.2 and then install it on that profile?  
i dont really understand the question... are you trying to install it on the default 1.7.4 profile?

Comment: @RustyMembers I'm trying to install it on the 1.6.2 profile. I'm an idiot, but not that much of an idiot. xD I download the 1.6.2 jar, copy the files into the correct folders and rename everything, and nothing shows up.

Comment: then i cant help you :(